# Files not being stored on S3 permanently using Paperclip, Heroku + AWS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, paperclip

I am using paperclip with heroku to store photos on my S3 on AWS. Everything seems to work fine and the images appear on my website but nothing shows up when i'm viewing the S3 bucket from the amazon dashboard. It shows the bucket is empty. Then, when my dev server on heroku 'spins down' next time I go to my app, the images are gone. It seems amazon is not persisting my images. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sounds like your images are being saved to the heroku local filesystem (which is lost when the dyno spins down). Could you post your paperclip configuration?

Answer (score 0):

Have you filled `has_attached_file` correctly in your model?

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image,
    :storage => :s3,
    :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
    :s3_credentials => {
      :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
      :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
    }
end
```

See this [tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) by Heroku and this for the [config-vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars).